# TypeScript: TypeError: App is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, typescript

I just started with typescript and trying to create an instance to the typescript class but I am unsuccessful.

Below are my files

App.ts

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

interface Emitter extends EventEmitter {

}
class App {
   constructor(protected app: Emitter){}
}

export default = App;
```

I am generating App.ts to `App.js` file using `tsc` command. The file got generated in dist folder as `App.js`

I have other file called Test.js

In Test.js I am importing generated App.js file and created an instance to it like below but I get below error

> TypeError: App is not a constructor

Test.js

```
const App = require("./dist/App);

module.exports = function(app){
    const appInstance = new App(app)
}
```

I don't understand why this is throwing such error though I have constructor available in App.ts file.

> Am I doing something wrong in App.ts file and that's why I get the above error?
>
> How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't the interface and the class be declared with different names? They are both called `App`. You can try declaring the interface as `IApp`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Sorry my bad it was typo error. I updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typescript compiles `export default = App;` as an export of an Object with a property **default**.

You can solve that with 2 methods:

1. Change your require in the js file to that: `const App = require("./dist/App).default;`
2. Add to your `tsconfig.json` file in the [compilerOptions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false`.

Comment: Awesome the first option resolved the issue but the second didn't work. You saved lot of time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

you have exported App by wrong way, export it like so

```
export default class App {
   constructor(protected app: App){}
}
```

Comment: But this is still valid right class App{} export default App; Can you please explain why this is not valid in typescript

Comment: I tried with your solution unfortunately I still get that error

Comment: because you can't set `export default` to equal smth., because there isn't syntax like it in typescript, instead you should add `export default` before `class, variable,function and so on` to export it, regarding error where is located your `Test.js` file? I think you wrote App.js path wrong

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because the file had the same name as the class.

Ie. `class MyThing {}` was defined in a file called `MyThing.ts`.

Renaming the file to `mything.ts` solved the problem.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have spent yesterday night and today trying to solve it and was only the file name.